# Issue with os.walk onerror argument

Tags: python, exception, os.walk

i searched everywhere but I could not find one explanation on how os.walk(onerror) works.

os.walk is defautly ignoring listdir() errors but I need to recieve at least alert, in better case path of directory which caused this error. How should I set up this argument?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Please. seach SO before posting your question. Chances are it is already answered. See the dupes answers.

Comment: @PatrickArtner  That's not a duplicate, in my opinion.  It asks why the error is ignored by default, this asks how to set up an error handler.

Comment: @wim The answers are. They cite the api on how to set up an errorhandler.?

Comment: @PatrickArtner  Are you looking at a different one than I am?  They don't show any code on how to setup a handler..

Comment: Why don't you post the message you mean as a comment  @PatrickArtner

Comment: @wim: they point to  [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and cite  `By default, errors from the listdir() call are ignored. If optional argument onerror is specified, it should be a function; it will be called with one argument, an OSError instance. It can report the error to continue with the walk, or raise the exception to abort the walk. Note that the filename is available as the filename attribute of the exception object.`

Comment: @PatrickArtner  That just regurgitates the docs, not as helpful for a beginner as providing a real example IMO.

Comment: @Wim Thats why you decided to answer and I decided to flag it as dupe after searching SO for all **of  10s** and finding an answer, a link to the documentation and a very easy to follow explanation of `Create a method that takes 1 param that is an OSError - raise it to break from os.walk or do smht/log it/ignore it  to continue walking` - provide the function to os.walk as onerror handler. The Q itself did not show any research effort beside the statement to _have searched everywhere_ nor any code or tries.

Comment: @PatrickArtner  What is obvious to us is not necessarily obvious to everyone.  All tasks eventually seem trivial in hindsight, and it's easy to forget what being a beginner was like.  If the answers on the "duplicate" were good then perhaps I would agree with you here, but I felt I could easily offer a better answer than was provided there.

Comment: @Wim thats why you got a +1 from me, yours is a nice answer. We have to agree to disagree on "was it needed".

Comment: @PatrickArtner Sorry for being amateur searching for clear answer. Im handling this kind of exception for first time and documentation was unclear for me and other tutorials I found were exact copies of documentation from pythons page.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+os.walk+onerror

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Python's os.walk fail silently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955283/why-does-pythons-os-walk-fail-silently)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error handler should be a callable.  It will be called with one argument, the exception instance.

```
def walk_error_handler(exception_instance):
    print("uh-oh!")  # you probably want to do something more substantial here..

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname, onerror=walk_error_handler):
    ...
```

`os.walk` ignoring errors by default is by design.  This allows the walk to continue to traverse other directories even after, for example, one subdirectory encountered in the walk could not be listed due to insufficient permissions.

When handling the exception instance, all the information you are interested in is likely contained in the `exception_instance.args` and the `type(exception_instance)`.  Since it's an `OSError` (or a subtype), the `errno` will be a useful attribute.

You can make comparisons against the constants of the stdlib [`errno`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html) module.  For example, permission denied is [`errno.EACCES`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html#errno.EACCES) (13).  That's the error you'd get if you tried to list `/root` as a normal user.

Comment: Is there any way to get atributes of error? I tried to call strerror() but it returned "TypeError: 'member_descriptor' object is not callable"

Comment: One more question. Is there any way to find out which file it was trying to open?

Comment: Yes: check the `exception_instance.filename` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. I hope it will help more people in similar situation.