# Trying to fetch all the files (including read only) from a directory using Python

Tags: python, filepath, listdir

I am new to Python - please excuse me if my question looks dumb.

I am trying to fetch all the files present in a given folder and create an Excel which shows file name and path.

It works fine on some folders, but not all. The reason which I think is maybe it's unable to fetch the data which is in read only mode (I am not quite sure of this).

Here is the error which I get:

> F:/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:/Vamsi_Folder/4.Tutorials/Python/OS/01-WIP/Get Files From  Directory/Get_Files_From_Directory.py", line 36, in 
>   List = getListOfFiles(filename)
>
> File "c:/Vamsi_Folder/4.Tutorials/Python/OS/01-WIP/Get Files From Directory/Get_Files_From_Directory.py", line 30, in getListOfFiles
>   allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
>
> File "c:/Vamsi_Folder/4.Tutorials/Python/OS/01-WIP/Get Files From Directory/Get_Files_From_Directory.py", line 22, in getListOfFiles
>   listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
>
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'F:/System Volume Information'

Here is the code which I am using:

```
#program to write files from directory in Excel


import os
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
import ntpath


Tk().withdraw()
filename = askdirectory()
print(filename)


def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    # create a list of file and sub directories 
    # names in the given directory 
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    # Iterate over all the entries
    for entry in listOfFile:
        # Create full path
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory 
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    return allFiles

List = getListOfFiles(filename)
Filename = []
for i in List:
    Filename.append(ntpath.basename(i))


workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active
worksheet.title = "Directory"

outlist = [Filename,List]

transpose = np.array(outlist).T
transpose_outlist = transpose.tolist()

worksheet.append(["Filename","Path"])

for row in transpose_outlist:
    worksheet.append(row)

count = "A1:""B"+str(len(List)+1)

tab = Table(displayName="Directory", ref=count)
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium9", showFirstColumn=False,
                       showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True)
tab.tableStyleInfo = style
worksheet.add_table(tab)

savename =asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",defaultextension="*.*",filetypes=\
                                     (("xml files","*.xml"),\
                                      ('xlsx files','.xlsx'),\
                                      ("all files","*.*")))

workbook.save(savename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to 'System Volume Information' of a hard disk partition.
[How to gain access to the System Volume Information folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/309531/how-to-gain-access-to-the-system-volume-information-folder#:~:text=The%20System%20Volume%20Information%20folder%20is%20a%20hidden%20system%20folder,this%20folder%20for%20troubleshooting%20purposes.)

Secondly, here is a better (pythonic) code, in my opinion, to get a list of all files in a directory and its subdirectories.

```
import os
import csv

directory = r'F:/'

files_list = [d + '\\' + f for d, dirs, files in os.walk(directory) for f in files]

with open('dicrectory_files.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(['basename', 'filepath'])
    for file in files_list:
        csv_writer.writerow([os.path.basename(file), file])
```

Then you can directly open this CSV in Excel.

If you don't want to enter the directory path directly in your code then you can change the directory path assignment statement with the following.

```
directory = input('Enter directory path: ')
if directory == '':
    directory = os.getcwd()
```

Then when you run the code file (.py), you just need to copy and paste the path of the directory you want to walk on in the prompt window. The CSV file will be created in the directory of your code file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but i am preparing this for my team. they will use this to audit the incoming files they want this information in excel. i know we can import the csv information in excel how ever its their requirement to get output in excel.

Comment: is there any way that i can skip that specific folder if the "access is denied". what i mean is i want program to continue even access is denied to one folder .

Comment: @user18457 `os.walk` by default ignores any error that occurs during traversing the directories. So by default skipping the "access is denied" error shouldn't be a problem as it will be ignored. But if you want to do something about that error, e.g printing the error message, then you can pass a custom function to `onerror` argument of `os.walk`, just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393057/issue-with-os-walk-onerror-argument) answer.

Comment: Thank you i have rewritten my code using os.walk it works like a charm

Comment: Is there a way that i can get the file properties information also. like i want to get file type from properties.

Comment: You can check the filetype from its extension. Use `os.path.splitext` function. or use `os.stat` function to check other stats of the file.

Or a better way would be using PowerShell if you are using windows.
`Dir 'F:/' -Recurse | Select-Objects * | ConvertTo-CSV | Out-File '.\directory files.csv'`

Comment: For help on Powershell [Dir Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7)